# Needle game with 3 payouts and fair game. Have two answers, but not sure which one.

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics

The question is below, followed by two answers. Both look like reasonable ones but I am not sure which one is right.

[image: Question]**Answer 1:**

[image: Answer1]**Answer 2:**

[image: Answer2]